# what is JCR in java and spring

Tags: java, spring, jcr

I have been learning java spring hibernate MVC for 3 months and got pretty idea of that . But i have not understood what JCR means.

I mean for e.g in my simple webiste in spring MVC what part can be done in JCR

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JCR would be an alternative persistence mechanism used in place of JPA (Hibernate), which hides JDBC from your application. In theory, the Java classes you have in your model might remain the same as you have now. However, if any classes in your model came about only because you needed to model some lower-level data structures for JPA, then these classes might not be needed with JCR.

You'd need a good reason to replace an existing use of JPA with JCR. For example, you may have discovered that using JPA requires jumping through a lot of extra hoops and doing things you'd not really need to do.

Having said that, JCR certainly has some advantages and capabilities that are not otherwise found in JPA:

1. JCR supports structured data, unstructured data, and everything in between. JCR allows a flexible schema and can be very NoSQL-ish. JPA is very structured, with a fixed schema.
2. JCR is hierarchical - some use cases are extremely hierarchical, and doing that with a relational model can be very difficult/expensive
3. JCR has built-in events
4. Most JCR implementations can store content in a variety of systems. Some can even access and federate existing content in other systems.
5. No length limitation of string values
6. JCR has full-text search support
7. JCR has multiple query languages, including JCR-SQL2 (very SQL-like)
8. There are some libraries that map Java classes to your node structures, and thus are very similar to JPA/Hibernate

It all depends on whether these features are beneficial for your application.

Comment: Randall:: Can you please tell me more about the API's you spoke in point 8. The Apis' that map Java Class to node.

Comment: There are a few libraries that map between Java objects and JCR nodes: Chromattic (https://code.google.com/p/chromattic/) and Jackrabbit OCM (http://jackrabbit.apache.org/object-content-mapping.html) are the two I'm familiar with. Personally, I don't like or recommend this kind of framework, because it basically ties your node schema to Java code, making it very difficult to use the powerful schema flexibility in JCR (point #1 above).

Answer (score 4):

Java Content Repository(JCR), tries to address these problems (and many others) in an implementation-independent way; that is, the API will be the same regardless of the underlying resource (eg a database, a local or virtual file system). Sitting on top of the data storage, JCR offers content services like granular access control, versioning, content events, full-text search and filtering among others. With an impressive expert group behind JSR-170 led by Day Software, including Content Management Systems (CMS) vendors like Vignette, Hummingbird Ltd., Stellent and the usual Java-driven solution providers like BEA Systems, IBM and Oracle, the specification is likely to become the de-facto standard for content management and document storage.

[image]

Comment: sorry man but i could not fully understood , i mean to e.g i have simple 5 page website build using spring MVC , mysql , hibernate . and its working . what will be the JCR role in that . i mean what JCR can do in my current scenario . i mean if i want to use it what extra feature it will add to my current site

Answer (score 4):

Re. the descision on when to use JCR vs. a relational data model, have a look at [david's model](http://wiki.apache.org/jackrabbit/DavidsModel). Was an eye-opener for me....